Evaluating an infinite series with a function
There is an infinite series, I want to transform it into a function, with digamma functions or something else. I hope someone can provide some guidance and suggestions.
$$
E(x,y)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-2x)^2+y^2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n)^2+y^2}})， \qquad 0<x<1
$$
I have plotted this function with Matplotlib by recursion, shown below (with y = 0.025).


I think this is not convergent. The terms are $\mathcal O(1/n)$ asymptotically, so it shares convergence with the harmonic series.

Sorry, I made a mistake with the sign, the first term should have a positive sign.

I have corrected the sign.

The graph is misleading. For $x=0$ the 2 terms cancel, so $E(0,y)=0$, the curve should run through the origin.

The range of x should be 0 < x < 1. I forgot to add the range.
